create a directory on /etc/samba/ via python
I am trying to create a directory on /etc/samba/ but I have the error:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/etc/samba/credentials'
My function is this:
samba_credentials_path = "/etc/samba/credentials"

# Funcion para crear el archivo de credenciales
def create_credentials_file(user, password, domain):
    try:
        os.makedirs(samba_credentials_path, 0o700, exist_ok=True)
    except FileExistsError:
        print("El directorio ya existe :D")


You need to run the program with more privileges (e.g., sudo).

Is this the only way? I mean its for automatize a samba share, how secure is this approach?

You could alter permissions so that your user has rights to create folders there, but this appears to be a file system permissions issue, not a python issue per se
